# HorizontalPager detect swipe offset

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I've a `HorizontalPager` with 3 items.

I need to know exact offset according to user's swipe

```
HorizontalPager(
            count = 3
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                contentDescription = ""
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Compose many views have some state parameter, using which you can check its state.

In case of pager, it the state has `currentPage` and `currentPageOffset` info. To calculate final offset you also need to check view size with `Modifier.onSizeChanged` or `BoxWithConstraints`.

I'm using [`derivedStateOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#derivedStateOf(kotlin.Function0)) to prevent redundant recompositions.

```kotlin
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
val (pagerWidth, setPagerWidth) = remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }
val scrollOffset by remember(pagerWidth) {
    derivedStateOf {
        if (pagerWidth == null) return@derivedStateOf 0f
        (pagerState.currentPage + pagerState.currentPageOffset) * pagerWidth
    }
}
HorizontalPager(
    state = pagerState,
    count = 3,
    modifier = Modifier
        .onSizeChanged {
            setPagerWidth(it.width)
        }
) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
        contentDescription = ""
    )
}
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
    contentDescription = "",
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .offset(x = with(LocalDensity.current) { -scrollOffset.toDp() })
)
```

Comment: I just developed custom view pager with Modifier.swipeable by my self because i couldnt find this answer :)